# ¿Como pasar información a una ventana modal?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY rand()")
or die("problemas en consulta ".mysql_error());
while ($reg=mysql_fetch_array($registro)) {
    echo "<div class='estilo1'>";   
    echo "<a href='#ventanaModal'>";
    echo "<img class='estilo2' src=' ". $reg['logo'] ." ' />";
    echo "</a>";    
    echo "<span class='estilo3'>". $reg['cliente'] ."</span>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<span class='estilo4'>". $reg['descripcion_corta'] ."</span>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<span class='estilo5'><b>". $reg['visitas'] ." </b><i>visitas</i></span>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</div>";
}
    echo "<div id='ventanaModal' class='modal'>";
    echo "<div class='modal-contenido'>";
        echo "<h2>". $reg['cliente'] ."</h2>";
    echo "<p>ejemplo de ventana modal con fondo negro</p>";
        echo "<a class='cerrar' href='#'>X</a>"; 
    echo "</div>";  
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

CSS de la modal es el siguiente:

```
<style>
.modal-contenido{
  background-color:aqua;
  width:300px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: relative;
}
.modal{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 1s;
}
div>ventanaModal:target{
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
</style>
```

El asunto es que en la pagina tengo unos cuadros con logos de los negocios de los clientes con información abajo, todo desde base de datos.

Le puse la ventana modal y al darle click al logo del cliente se oscurece y aparece una ventana modal, pero no aparece información del cliente al que le di click, es decir debería de aparecer en la información de la ventana modal información del cliente al que le di click y su respectiva información que tengo en la base de datos, el ejemplo es que para empezar no me arroja el nombre del cliente en la ventana modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema:

> Mostrar los datos de los distintos clientes en un mismo modal

Solución:

- Crear una función en `javascript` (`mostrarCliente`) y asignarla al `onclick` del logo de los clientes. Esta recibe por parámetro la referencia al `div.estilo1`
- Identificar a través de clases los elementos que contienen el nombre (`cliente-nombre`) y la descripción (`cliente-descripcion`) del cliente.
- Identificar a través de clases los elementos en el `modal` donde se mostrara el nombre (`modal-nombre`) y la descripción (`modal-descripcion`) del cliente.

El código podría ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$registro = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY rand()")
or die("problemas en consulta ".mysql_error());
while ($reg=mysql_fetch_array($registro)) {
?>
<div class="estilo1">
  <a href="#ventanaModal" onclick="mostrarCliente(this.parentElement)"><img class="estilo2" src="<?php echo $reg['logo']; ?>" alt="logo" /></a>
  <span class="estilo3 cliente-nombre"><?php echo $reg['cliente']; ?></span>
  <br>
  <span class="estilo4 cliente-descripcion"><?php echo $reg['descripcion_corta']; ?></span>
  <br>
  <span class="estilo5"><b><?php echo $reg['visitas']; ?> </b><i>visitas</i></span>
  <br>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<div id="ventanaModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-contenido">
    <h2 class="modal-nombre"></h2>
    <p class="modal-descripcion"></p>
    <a class='cerrar' href='#'>X</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function mostrarCliente (contenedor) {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ventanaModal');

  // Cliente
  modal.getElementsByClassName('modal-nombre')[0].innerText = contenedor.getElementsByClassName('cliente-nombre')[0].innerText;
  // Descripcion
  modal.getElementsByClassName('modal-descripcion')[0].innerText = contenedor.getElementsByClassName('cliente-descripcion')[0].innerText;
}
</script>
```

//

Demo funcional aquí:

```js
function mostrarCliente (contenedor) {
  var modal = document.getElementById('ventanaModal');
  
  // Cliente
  modal.getElementsByClassName('modal-nombre')[0].innerText = contenedor.getElementsByClassName('cliente-nombre')[0].innerText;
  // Descripcion
  modal.getElementsByClassName('modal-descripcion')[0].innerText = contenedor.getElementsByClassName('cliente-descripcion')[0].innerText;
}
```

```css
.modal-contenido{
  background-color:aqua;
  width:300px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  position: relative;
}
.modal{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  transition: all 1s;
}
div#ventanaModal:target{
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="estilo1">
  <a href="#ventanaModal" onclick="mostrarCliente(this.parentElement)"><img class="estilo2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Coca-Cola_logo.svg/64px-Coca-Cola_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" /></a>
  <span class="estilo3 cliente-nombre">Coca-Cola</span>
  <br>
  <span class="estilo4 cliente-descripcion">Coca-Cola es una bebida efervescente, vendida en más de doscientos países o territorios.</span>
  <br>
  <span class="estilo5"><b>10 </b><i>visitas</i></span>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="estilo1">
  <a href="#ventanaModal" onclick="mostrarCliente(this.parentElement)"><img class="estilo2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0f/Pepsi_logo_2014.svg/64px-Pepsi_logo_2014.svg.png" alt="logo" /></a>
  <span class="estilo3 cliente-nombre">Pepsi</span>
  <br>
  <span class="estilo4 cliente-descripcion">Pepsi, es una bebida carbonatada de cola producida por la compañía PepsiCo</span>
  <br>
  <span class="estilo5"><b>9 </b><i>visitas</i></span>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="ventanaModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-contenido">
    <h2 class="modal-nombre"></h2>
    <p class="modal-descripcion"></p>
    <a class='cerrar' href='#'>X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Más aún, se deberían de usar clases en vez de ID's para identificar las ventanas modales.

Comment: Yo la verdad que iba a contestar pero no quería basarme simplemente en suposiciones. Y más que "no es buena práctica": Sí es buena práctica si se utilizan en el lugar adecuado :)

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios, no usa javascrip la modal es puro css.. lo agrego..

Comment: almenos que en el css se pueda poner . $reg['id'] . algo asi para que recoja el valor y quitar "ventanamodal".. no? disculpen mi ignorancia

Comment: si funciona como el ejemplo pero como dices una modal independiente con su id y si son 100 clientes no es practico hacer 100 modales.. almenos asi les entendi..